# Why this gridview is empty and how I can better check null?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, object, null

What's wrong in this code? Code works, but it returns empty gridview?
If I debug code, I can see that my string plName contains players name, however when I add it to object it's empty? Also, how I can check if my query result is null? I believe this is not best way to do it...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if(!IsPostback) 
    {
        List<AllPlayers> listOfPlayers  = new List<AllPlayers>();

        string plName = "";
        string plStatus = "";

        using (PlayerEntities playerEntities = new PlayerEntities())
        {
            var query = (from pl in playerEntities.players from st in playerEntities.player_status.Where(a => a.players_key == pl.players_key).DefaultIfEmpty() 
            from pt in playerEntities.play_times.Where(b => b.players_key == pl.players_key).DefaultIfEmpty() select new { pl, st, pt }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                plName = item.pl.player_name.ToString();

                try // better way check if this is NULL ?
                {
                    plName = item.st.default_times_start.ToString();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.Message.ToString();
                }

                AllPlayers demo = new AllPlayers(plName, plStatus);

                listOfPlayers.Add(demo);
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = listOfPlayers;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
    }
```

ASPX:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you move the `GridView1.DataSource = listOfPlayers; GridView1.DataBind();` outside the loop and wrap the code inside `if(!IsPostback) { /* here */ }` ? Also how did you declare the `GridView`? Using AutoGenerateColumns or define the column template? Please also show the `GridView` code in the aspx file..

Comment: My bad, your right that gridview should be outside the loop.

Comment: Your current code seems fine. Could you try putting all of the code in the page load inside `if(!IsPostback) { /* here */ }`? And could you also please show the `AllPlayers` class ?

Comment: Problem was inside AllPlayers class. However, any advice how I can handle if one of query result is null? Example one player do not have default time?

Comment: The catch block do nothing if the exception has occured.

Comment: check for nulls with == System.DBNull.Value